# How to Render different Layouts in Asp.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to render empty layout on some pages in my asp.net core app. For this, I have used this code in `_ViewStart.cshtml`.

```
@{
    var controller = HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"].ToString();
    string cLayout = "";
    if (controller == "Empty")
    {
        cLayout = "~/Views/Shared/_Empty_Layout.cshtml";
    }
    else
    {
        cLayout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }
    Layout = cLayout;
}
```

This code is working fine for `Asp.NET MVC App` but it gives the error in `.NET Core App`. The error is `The name 'HttpContext' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: You can set the `Layout` in a code block on any page.  There's no need to check it like this in `_ViewStart`.  Set `Layout = "_Empty_Layout"` in the page that uses that layout.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`HttpContext.Current` was a very bad idea from Microsoft, which, fortunately, was **not** migrated to ASP.NET Core.

You can access `RouteData` like this:

```
@Url.ActionContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"]
// or
@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"]
```

That said, "empty layout" sounds like you do not want a layout at all. If that's the case, use this:

```
@{
    var controller = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"].ToString();
    string layout = null;
    if (controller != "Empty")
    {
        layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }
    Layout = layout;
}
```

`null` here means "do not use a layout".

Comment: Perhaps `ViewContext.RouteData` would be simpler?

Comment: @Brad Thanks, I knew there had to be a shorted path.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, I'm using Asp.Net Core 2.2 and you approach is working like sharp. a big thanks